# Incorrect frequency on manually drawn graph

Tags: android, graph, fft

I am currently writting a a spectrum analyzer for android for university and part of this involves plotting the FFT of sound. However, I am having an issue with plotting the frequencies. The freq values start off correct, but as i move to higher frequencies the error is becoming greater and greater (at 3000Hz, the graph will show ~3750). I feel as though there is an error in the way I am calculating the x-axis or freq values. This is a manually drawn graph for speed purposes.

If more info/code is needed just let me know, but my guess is that it is something simple that I have overlooked. Thanks

xVal is the frequency value. and the scale value is to scale it according to the real graph dimensions.

```
    int length = currentWaveDataDouble.length;
    int pow2 = Integer.highestOneBit(length) << 1;
    int sampleRate = 44100;
    ...
    //actual plot part
    for(int i =0; i<p2.length; i++) {
        float xVal = (float)(i * scaleX.ScaleValue(((double) sampleRate / (pow2 >> 1))));
        if (xVal < maxFreqPlus1) {
            xVal += axisWidth + yAxisMargin;
            float yVal = (float) scaleY.ScaleValue(p2[i]);
            yVal += axisWidth + xAxisMargin;

            canvas.drawPoint(xVal,yVal, marker);

            if(yVal > yMax)
            {
                yMax = yVal;
                xMax = xVal;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Freq generator set to 4000 Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxfra.jpg)

[Freq generator set to 1000 Hz (value is 1250Hz)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZYIw.jpg)

Comment: give more info about it and show how result of your code on spectrum look like

Comment: I have added some screenshots. What other information is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. it was in the scaler.

```
    ValueScaler scaleY = new ValueScaler(0,maxAmpPlus1 - yAxisMargin,0,baseY);
    ValueScaler scaleX = new ValueScaler(0,maxFreqPlus1 - xAxisMargin,0,baseX);
```

i wasn't taking into account the x and y margin when scaling the numbers.